# Autolayout: Reset Bottom Constrain After Toolbar is Hidden

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have a tableview that has it's bottom constrain set to the top of a toolbar, however, I sometimes hide this toolbar when the buttons are unnecessary.

How do I set up my tableview's bottom constraint to now be the bottom of the screen sans toolbar?

Do I set 2 bottom constraints in storyboard? Do I swap these out programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding view does't remove it from the layout calculations. You must do one of the following:

- Have a constraint to align toolbar bottom to the bottom of the screen
- Have a constraint to hold toolbar height
- Reset that second constraint to 0 when you're hiding toolbar

or

- Change the value for the constraint that align bottom of your tableView with top of the toolbar by adding/removing value equal to toolbar height